# How can I associate a GPU to each CPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have a question :

Let's say I have 2 GPU:s in my system and I have 2 host processes running cuda code. How can I be sure that each takes a GPU?

I'm considering setting exclusive_thread but I cannot understand how to get advantage of it: once I check that a device is free how can I be sure that it remains free until I do a cudaSetDevice?

**EDIT:**

So far I've tried this:

```
int devN = 0; 
while (cudaSuccess != cudaSetDevice(devN))devN = (devN + 1) % 2;
```

but I get a

```
CUDA Runtime API error 77: an illegal memory access was encountered.
```

which is not strange since I am in EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS mode.

Comment: You can't ensure that a device remains free, if you have multiple processes competing for it.  CUDA by itself does not sort this out for you.  The best mechanism is to use a job scheduler or other resource allocation system.  If you have 2 host threads and 2 GPUs, and no other processes/threads competing for those GPUs, then `cudaSetDevice()` will work fine.

Comment: So my question can be restated like this: How do I know that I am on host 1? I have tried GetCurrentProcessorNumber() and it is not of help.

Comment: For threads belonging to the same multi-threaded application, it will depend on the threading model you use in your code.  processes and threads are generally not the same thing.  If you are in fact talking about separate host processes, then you should clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks Crovella, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two elements within this question. Assigning a process to a GPU and making sure a GPU is available for a single process.

#### Assigning a process to a GPU

There is a simple way to accomplish this using CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable: start you first process with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` and your second process with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`. Each process will see a single GPU, with device index 0, and will see a different GPU.

Running `nvidia-smi topo -m` will display GPU topology and provide you with the corresponding CPU affinity.

Then, you may set CPU affinity for your process with `taskset` or `numactl` on linux or `SetProcessAffinityMask` on Windows.

#### Process has exclusive access to a GPU

To make sure that no other process may access your GPU, configure the GPU driver to be in exclusive process: `nvidia-smi --compute-mode=1`.

Comment: I've tried this: 

  int devN = 0;
  while (cudaSuccess != cudaSetDevice(devN)){
    devN = (devN + 1) % 4;
  }
but I get a "CUDA Runtime API error 77: an illegal memory access was encountered."

Comment: That means you have broken kernel code somewhere.  It doesn't have anything to do with setting or choosing a device.